# My game won't work when I use the controls, how do I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I can not get the controls to work, I try to press escape to open a menu I made but it will not open and I do not know if I am checking for events correctly, is there a way I am SUPPOSED to do it?

I tried using the functions for checking for different keys and I went to the spread-sheet that displays all the event names so you can map them at pygame.org but it will not open when I use the escape or also known as:

```
elif event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
    Frame.blit('Textures/GUI/loom.png', (0,0))
```

Heres the full code:

```
import pygame

#Textures/Blocks/loom_side.png

pygame.init()

Screen = "None"

DB = 0

Width = 800

Height = 600

Frame = pygame.display.set_mode((Width,Height))

pygame.display.set_caption("HypoPixel")

FPS = pygame.time.Clock()

def Raycast(TTR, RayXPos, RayYPos, RaySizeX, RaySizeY):
    RaycastThis = pygame.image.load(TTR)
    RaycastThis = pygame.transform.scale(RaycastThis,(RaySizeX,RaySizeY))
    Frame.blit(RaycastThis, (RayXPos, RayYPos))
Loop = True
Raycast('Textures/Screens/Skybox/Earth.png',0,0,800,600)
while Loop == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            Frame.blit('Textures/GUI/loom.png', (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()

    FPS.tick(60)
```

I expected to get the loom GUI that I made. Once I tried to press escape, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pygame.K_ESCAPE` is not event type (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)), but it is a [`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html).

First check if a key was pressed by comparing the event type to `pygame.KEYDOWN`:

```py
event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN
```

Then check if the `event.key`, which cause the event, is the `pygame.K_ESCAPE` key:

```py
event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE
```

Furthermore, the parameter to [`Surface.blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) has to be a `Surface` object rather than a filename.

first load the image to a `Surface`, by [`pygame.image.load()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load), then `blit` the `Surface`:

```py
sprite = pygame.image.load('Textures/GUI/loom.png')
Frame.blit(sprite, (0,0))
```

Of course the your `Raycast` function can be called to do so:

```py
Raycast('Textures/GUI/loom.png',0,0,800,600)
```

Your code should look somehow like this:

```py
while Loop == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            Raycast('Textures/GUI/loom.png',0,0,800,600)
```

Comment: thank you it helped a lot! Also that part about making a new sprite to blit was actually defined by my Raycast function! but thanks again that helped